# Joining 2nd Table with Random Row to each record

Tags: sql-server, join, random

I need to join table B to Table A, where Table B's records are randomly assigned, or joined. Most of the queries out there are based off of having a key between them and conditions, where I just want to randomly join records without a key.

I'm not sure where to start, as none of the queries I've found are doing this. I assume a nested join could be helpful for this, but how can I randomly assort the records on join?

```
**Table A**
| Associate ID| Statement|
|:----:  |:------:|
| 33691| John is |
| 82451| Susie is |
| 25485| Sam is|
| 26582| Lonnie is|
| 52548| Carl is|

**Table B**
| RowID | List|
|:----:  |:------:|
| 1| admirable|
| 2| astounding|
| 3| excellent|
| 4| awesome|
| 5| first class|
```

The result would be something like this, where items from the list are not looped through in order, but random:

```
**Result Table**
| Associate ID| Statement| List|
|:----:  |:------:|:------:|
| 33691| John is |astounding|
| 82451| Susie is |first class|
| 25485| Sam is|admirable|
| 26582| Lonnie is|excellent|
| 52548| Carl is|awesome|
```

These are some of the queries I've tried:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aeb83251-e132-435a-8630-e5b842a69368/random-join-between-tables?forum=sqldataaccess
  -This seems to loop through values from 'Table B', not random.
- https://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2009/08/11/mysql-select-random-row-with-join
  -This is based off of a common key between the two tables and returning one of the records with the key, which I do not have.
- [SQL Join help when selecting random row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420754/sql-join-help-when-selecting-random-row)
  - I'll be honest, I don't understand this one, but it doesn't seem to assign random for each row from Table A, but more of a selection overall link the link above this.
- [Join One Table To Get Random Rows from 2nd Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031353/join-one-table-to-get-random-rows-from-2nd-table)
  - This seems to be specific to a key, and not an overall random.

Comment: Assign a row number based on a a random order to both tables. and then join on the row number generated

Comment: How would that work when having undetermined records in Table A (1-10,000), and a small amount in Table B? (1-50)

Comment: Wait... So each record in A must be paird with a random record in B? or should there be an equal number of record from B paird with a random record in A?  (meaning if there are only 50 records in B, it would be 50*X and not the case where 1 record in B could be 100* more than another...  Put another way.  Are you after a true random pairing for each record in A to B or 50 records from B should be repeated X times until all records in A could be accounted for and then joined to A...  So it would be like count(A)/Count(B) +1 * all records in B randomized then joined to A.

Comment: a recursive CTE would allow you to repeat the 50 records N times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327837/repeat-rows-n-times-according-to-column-value getting the count as described above and then assigning a row number would work; but this assumes an even distribution of records from B... Otherwise you could cross apply to B order by Rand() and get top 1.  So... are you after Even distribution from B, or truly a random distribution from B? well... as truely random as Rand() function gives you...

Comment: Are you after a Random Distribution from B or an Even Distribution from B? (Assuming `Rand()` is good enough for Random)

Answer (score 1):

This method assumes you know in advance which is the smaller table.

First it assigns an ascending row numbering from `1`. This does not have to be randomized.

Then for each row in the larger table it uses the modulus operator to randomly calculate a row number in the range to join onto.

```
WITH Small
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RN
         FROM   SmallTable),
     Large
     AS (SELECT *,
                1 + CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3) % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SmallTable) AS RND
         FROM   LargeTable
         ORDER  BY RND
         OFFSET 0 ROWS)
SELECT *
FROM   Large
       INNER JOIN Small
               ON Small.RN = Large.RND
```

The `ORDER  BY RND OFFSET 0 ROWS` is to get the random numbers materialized in advance.

This will allow a `MERGE` join on the smaller table. It also avoids an issue that can sometimes happen where the `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` is moved around in the plan and only evaluated once rather than once per row as required.

Answer (score 0):

using 2 CTEs we generate a select which generates a row number for each table based on a random order and then join based on that row number.

Using a CTE to get N times the records in B as described here:
[Repeat Rows N Times According to Column Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327837/repeat-rows-n-times-according-to-column-value)  (Not included below)  Note to get the "N" you'll need to get count from A and B, then divide by eachother and Add 1.

Assuming Even Distribution

```
With A as(
SELECT *, Row_number() over (order by NewID()) RN
FROM A),
B as (
SELECT *, Row_number () over (order by NewID()) RN
FROM B)
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
 on A.RN = B.RN
```

Or use (assuming uneven distribution)

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM B ORDER BY NewID()) Z
```

Comment: `rand()` is a runtime constant and the same for all rows so `Row_number() over (order by rand())` doesn't apply any randomisation at all

Comment: Hm... I guess I forot that NEWID then.  though I'm not sure about performance... and duplication is possible...  I guess the right method is: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/955/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-random-ordering